# How to overlay png image on Android map and specify four anchor points 

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android map application. I need to overlay a route image which displays the route on the map. But, when we zoom in or zoom out the image will not scale with it because it is only anchored to a fixed center point. I want to anchor it with four boundary points such that it will scale with the map.

Can someone please suggest a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale a bitmap using the [createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) method.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Is there no way of anchoring the image with the rectangle borders?

Comment: I don't know about that. I'm not sure how you'd "anchor" and image to a map.